# Mount folder using ssh twice (first ssh to gate, then from gate to workstation)

Tags: mount, ssh, sftp

My current situation is that I have my personal laptop, and I there is a workstation I need to be able to mount. But before I can get to that workstation, I first need to ssh into the gate of the network.

So basically, if I only want to connect to the workstation I need to do this:

> ssh username@gate
>
> $ ssh username@workstation

Is there a way for me to mount the workstation directly into ubuntu? So I can work on my documents on the workstation?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with [SSH-forwarding](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/06/ssh-port-forwarding/). E.g.

```
$ ssh -f -L 2200:username@workstation:22 username@gate -N
$ sshfs -p 2200 localhost:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/mount/point
```

However, the administrator of your gateway computer might have disabled SSH forwarding, in which case I think you're out of luck with this option.

Another possibility is to use [SSH-bouncing](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20040830.html). IMHO it is a bit more involved and requires you to possibly install netcat on the gateway machine.

Comment: Well, I tried the first option, but I get 

channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
read: Connection reset by peer

Does this mean the SSH forwarding is disabled?

I also have no admin rights on the gate box, so that's no option...

Comment: Yep, the admin was careful and closed that loophole.